# How to configure Apache Maven settings.xml to prevent downloading specific dependecies\plugin

Tags: maven

I want to configure settings.xml to prevent downloading vulnerable versions of log4j.
I see that maven can banned specific dependencies defined in pom.xml, but can it also be done in settings.xml?

Comment: Simple answer: You can not... use a repository manager and/or maven-enforcer-plugin to fail the build...

Comment: hi @khmarbaise, is there other way that we can block the download of specific dependency in maven?